# Need JSON data to display multiple arrays with foreach

Tags: php, json, foreach

I am trying to display information from JSON data I created using a PHP for each loop.I am having an issue with the multidimensional array. I can't select them all at once and when there is 30 I don't want to have 30 for each loops.

Here is my Json data:

```
[
{
    "country": "us",
    "city_ascii": "destin",
    "city": "Destin",
    "region": "FL",
    "population": "12115",
    "latitude": "30.393333",
    "longitude": "-86.495833"
},
{
    "country": "us",
    "city_ascii": "destino",
    "city": "Destino",
    "region": "PR",
    "population": "0",
    "latitude": "18.130278",
    "longitude": "-65.436667"
}
]
```

Here is my PHP for handling the JSON:

```
$json = json_encode($rows,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

$data = json_decode($json);


foreach($data[0] as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'city_ascii' || $key == 'latitude' || $key == 'longitude') {

    } else{
        echo $key.' '.$value.'<br>';
    }
}
```

as you can see I have selected $data[0], in reality I want every array displayed from the JSON in this foreach loop. I hope I am explaining myself thoroughly. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you encoding and then decoding the data? Just loop over `$rows`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need multiple loops. All you need is

```
foreach($data as $location)
{
  echo $location->city;  // or country or whatever
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/194437)**

Comment: I suppose I was doing it wrong. Every time I used "foreach($data as $key=>$value){}" I got an error. could you explain why?

Comment: Nope you weren't doing `foreach($data`, you were doing `foreach($data[0]` and that is only the first value of that array. If it does not have sub arrays that loop won't work.

Answer (score 1):

decode your json data as an array with passing `true` parameter in `json_decode` and iterate all loop Try

```
$str = '[
{
    "country": "us",
    "city_ascii": "destin",
    "city": "Destin",
    "region": "FL",
    "population": "12115",
    "latitude": "30.393333",
    "longitude": "-86.495833"
},
{
    "country": "us",
    "city_ascii": "destino",
    "city": "Destino",
    "region": "PR",
    "population": "0",
    "latitude": "18.130278",
    "longitude": "-65.436667"
}
]';
$json = json_decode($str, true);

foreach($json as $k=>$v) {
  foreach($v as $k1=>$v1) {
    if($k1 == 'city_ascii' || $k1 == 'latitude' || $k1 == 'longitude'){}
    else{ echo $k1.' '.$v1.'<br>';}
  }
}
```

will give you output:-

```
country us
city Destin
region FL
population 12115
country us
city Destino
region PR
population 0
```